# How to put socail share button in WordPress post under the post excerpt?

Tags: wordpress, button, plugins

Is there any plugin to put social share button under a WordPress post excerpt?

Please see this image to understand what I want.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything research or code wise to try and achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a WordPress plugin called [Share Buttons](http://wordpress.org/plugins/add-to-any/) to achieve this. Once installed, activated and chosen what icons you want added. Add the following to the page(s) with the excerpt (just after calling the excerpt).

```
<?php if ( function_exists( 'ADDTOANY_SHARE_SAVE_KIT' ) ) { ADDTOANY_SHARE_SAVE_KIT(); } ?>
```

The code would be something like:

```
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<?php if ( function_exists( 'ADDTOANY_SHARE_SAVE_KIT' ) ) { ADDTOANY_SHARE_SAVE_KIT(); } ?>
```

It might be different depending on how you have done the excerpt.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another method using genericons

First, download and intall the [genericon pack](http://genericons.com/) in your theme. Enqueue the genericon stylesheet

```
function enqueue_genericon_style() {
      wp_enqueue_style( 'genericons', get_template_directory_uri() . '/genericons/genericons.css', array(), '3.0.2' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_genericon_style' );
```

Add the following to your functions.php. This functions do all the hard work by adding the share url and genericons

```
function pietergoosen_social_share_buttons() {
    $services = array (
        'facebook' => array (
            'url'  => 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=%1$s',
            'text' => esc_attr(__('Share on Facebook.', 'pietergoosen' )),
            'icon' => '<span class="genericon genericon-facebook"></span>'
        ),
        'twitter' => array (
            'url'  => 'http://twitter.com/home/?status=%1$s%%20-%%20%2$s',
            'text' => esc_attr(__('Tweet this post!', 'pietergoosen' )),
            'icon' => '<span class="genericon genericon-twitter"></span>'
        ),
        'googleplus' => array (
            'url'  => 'https://plus.google.com/share?url=%1$s',
            'text' => esc_attr(__('Google+1.', 'pietergoosen' )),
            'icon' => '<span class="genericon genericon-googleplus"></span>'
        ),
        'linkedin' => array (
            'url'  => 'https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=%1$s&amp;title=%2$s&amp;summary=%3$s&amp;source=%4$s',
            'text' => esc_attr(__('linkedin.', 'pietergoosen' )),
            'icon' => '<span class="genericon genericon-linkedin"></span>'
        ),
        'reddit' => array (
            'url'  => 'http://reddit.com/submit?url=%1$s&amp;title=%2$s',
            'text' => esc_attr(__('Reddit.', 'pietergoosen' )),
            'icon' => '<span class="genericon genericon-reddit"></span>'
        ),
        'stumbleupon' => array (
            'url'  => 'http://www.stumbleupon.com/submit?url=%1$s&amp;title=%2$s',
            'text' => esc_attr(__('StumbleUpon.', 'pietergoosen' )),
            'icon' => '<span class="genericon genericon-stumbleupon"></span>'
        ),
        'digg' => array (
            'url'  => 'http://digg.com/submit?phase=2&amp;url=%1$s&amp;title=%2$s',
            'text' => esc_attr(__('Digg this post!', 'pietergoosen' )),
            'icon' => '<span class="genericon genericon-digg"></span>'
        ),
        'gmail' => array (
            'url'  => 'https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&amp;fs=1&amp;to&amp;su=%1$s&amp;t=%2$s',
            'text' => esc_attr(__('Share with Gmail', 'pietergoosen' )),
            'icon' => '<span class="genericon genericon-mail"></span>'
        )
    );

    $title    = the_title_attribute( array ( 'echo' => FALSE ) );
    $url      = urlencode( get_permalink() );
    $summary  = the_excerpt();
    $source   = '';

    print '<h4>' . __( 'Share this post with others', 'pietergoosen' ) . '</h4>';

    echo '<div class="socialgenericons service">';

        foreach ( $services as $name  => $service )
        {
            $href = sprintf( $service['url'], $url, urlencode( $title ), urlencode( $summary ), urlencode( $source ) );
            $genericon = $service['icon'];

            printf(
                '<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" alt="%2$s">%3$s</a>',
                $href,
                $service['text'],
                $genericon
            );
        }

    echo '</div>';  
}
```

Now add `<?php pietergoosen_social_share_buttons(); ?>` in your content.php where you need to display the buttons.

To open a pop-up when a link is clicked, add the following in your `enqueue_genericon_style()` function.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'pietergoosen-socialshare', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/socialshare.popup.js', array( 'jquery' ), '' , true );
```

Now create a js folder in your theme if you don't have one. Create a file called `socialshare.popup.js` in the js folder. Now add the following in that file

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    jQuery('.socialgenericons.service a').live('click', function(){

        newwindow=window.open($(this).attr('href'),'','height=450,width=700');

        if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}

        return false;

    });

});
```

This should do the trick. Your buttons will look like this. You just need to style the genericons accordingly

[image: Social buttons]

**EDIT**

I use a custom excerpt, so I changed that to `the_excerpt()` for the purpose of this answer, otherwise you will get a fatal error.