# Social share under excerpt

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Please tell me is there any plugin to put social share button under wordpress post excerpt? Like the website below?

http://spiritual-quotes.org/

I have seen an answer from someone else on this site saying

You can use a WordPress plugin called Share Buttons to achieve this. Once installed, activated and chosen what icons you want added. Add the following to the page(s) with the excerpt (just after calling the excerpt).

```
<?php if ( function_exists( 'ADDTOANY_SHARE_SAVE_KIT' ) ) { ADDTOANY_SHARE_SAVE_KIT(); } ?>
```

The code would be something like:

```
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<?php if ( function_exists( 'ADDTOANY_SHARE_SAVE_KIT' ) ) { ADDTOANY_SHARE_SAVE_KIT(); } ?    >
```

It might be different depending on how you have done the excerpt.

I am using the Valenti theme http://valenti.cubellthemes.com/tag/beats/

I just need to know where I need to past the above code to get it to work.

Hope you can help

Thanks

Hi here is the code in archive.php

```
<?php
        get_header();
        $cb_global_color = ot_get_option('cb_base_color', '#eb9812');
        $cb_theme_style = ot_get_option('cb_theme_style', 'cb_boxed');
?>

<div class="cb-cat-header<?php if ($cb_theme_style == 'cb_boxed') echo ' wrap'; ?>"       style="border-bottom-color:<?php echo $cb_global_color; ?>;">
 <?php if (is_day()) { ?>
        <h1 id="cb-cat-title">
            <span><?php _e("Daily Archives", "cubell"); ?> <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></span> <?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?>
        </h1>

    <?php } elseif (is_month()) { ?>
        <h1 id="cb-cat-title">
            <span><?php _e("Monthly Archives", "cubell"); ?> <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></span> <?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?>
        </h1>

    <?php } elseif (is_year()) { ?>
        <h1 id="cb-cat-title">
            <span><?php _e("Yearly Archives", "cubell"); ?> <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></span> <?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?>
        </h1>
    <?php } ?>
```

```
<div id="main" class="clearfix" role="main">

    <?php if (have_posts()) {

                        get_template_part('cat', 'style-a');
         } ?>

</div> <!-- end #main -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

Where would I put the code?

Thanks
@sirBlond
Hi here is the code from cat-style-a.php

Thanks again :) nearly there

```
<?php /* Category/Blog Style A */

if ( is_home() || is_category() ) {

  $cb_current_cat = get_query_var('cat');
  $cb_cpt_output = cb_get_custom_post_types();
  $cb_paged = get_query_var('paged');
  $cb_grid_size = NULL;

  if ( $cb_paged == false ) {
    $cb_paged = 1;
  }

  if ( is_category() == true ) {
    $cb_grid_size = cb_get_category_offset();
  } elseif ( is_home() == true ) {
    $cb_grid_size = cb_get_bloghome_offset();
  }

  if ( $cb_grid_size != NULL ) {
    $cb_offset_loop = 'on';
  } else {
    $cb_offset_loop = NULL;
  }

  $cb_featured_qry = array( 'post_type' => $cb_cpt_output, 'cat' => $cb_current_cat, 'offset' => $cb_grid_size, 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC',  'post_status' => 'publish', 'cb_offset_loop' => $cb_offset_loop, 'paged' => $cb_paged );
  $cb_qry = new WP_Query( $cb_featured_qry );

} else {

  global $wp_query;
  $cb_qry = $wp_query;

}

if ( ! isset( $cb_category_color_style ) ) {
    $cb_category_color_style = NULL;
  }

if ( $cb_qry->have_posts() ) : while ( $cb_qry->have_posts() ) : $cb_qry->the_post();

  $cb_meta_onoff = ot_get_option( 'cb_meta_onoff', 'on' );
  $cb_cat_id = get_the_category( $post->ID );
  $cb_post_id = $post->ID;
  $cb_post_format_icon = cb_post_format_check( $cb_post_id );
  $cb_global_color = ot_get_option( 'cb_base_color', '#eb9812' );

  $cb_category_color = cb_get_cat_color( $cb_post_id );
?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="cb-blog-style-a clearfix<?php if (is_sticky()) echo ' sticky'; if ( $cb_category_color_style != NULL ) { echo ' ' . $cb_category_color_style; } ?>" role="article">

  <div class="cb-mask" style="background-color:<?php echo $cb_category_color; ?>;">

    <?php
        cb_thumbnail('300', '200');
        echo cb_review_ext_box( $cb_post_id, $cb_category_color );
        echo $cb_post_format_icon;
    ?>

  </div>

  <div class="cb-meta">

      <h2 class="h4"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
      <?php echo cb_byline(); ?>
      <div class="cb-excerpt"><?php echo cb_clean_excerpt( 210, false ); ?></div>

  </div>

</article>

<?php

  endwhile;
  cb_page_navi();
  endif;
  wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made a similar thing with [sharethis](http://www.sharethis.com/get-sharing/website-widgets/wordpress-widget/) plugin ([link to WP repo](https://wordpress.org/plugins/share-this/)). It provides a ready template tag to use wherever you want it.

Here's my implementation of addthis buttons in widget:

```
<ul class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style footer-social-list">
  <li><a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a></li>
  <li><a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a></li>
  <li><a class="addthis_button_google_plusone" g:plusone:annotation="bubble" g:plusone:size="medium"></a> </li>
  <li><a class="icon icon_rss" href="<?php bloginfo('url');?>/feed/"></a></li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js"></script>
```

... and here's a part of template implementation:

```
<div class="blog-post-soc">
    <?php
        $json = file_get_contents("http://api.sharedcount.com/?url=" . rawurlencode(get_permalink()));
        $counts = json_decode($json, true);
    ?>
    <ul class="social-count-button-lists">
        <li>
            <span class="icon icon25 icon_gplus"></span>
            <span class="count"><?php echo  $counts["GooglePlusOne"] ?></span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="icon icon25 icon_twitter"></span>
            <span class="count"><?php echo  $counts["Twitter"] ?></span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="icon icon25 icon_fb"></span>
            <span class="count"><?php echo  $counts["Facebook"]["like_count"] ?></span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="icon icon25 icon_in"></span>
            <span class="count"><?php echo  $counts["LinkedIn"] ?></span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="icon icon25 icon_pin"></span>
            <span class="count"><?php echo  $counts["Pinterest"] ?></span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php get_bloginfo('url') ?>/feed/" class="icon icon25 icon_rss"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

That's kinda old implementation (WP 3.1), but I don't think that something changed so far.

Also there's another option. You can use your code, but you need to paste it into archive.php or index.php (or both) just before the end of the loop - it'll smth similar to this:

`while(have_posts()):
  #some code here
  the_excerpt(); //or the_content();
  if (function_exists('ADDTOANY_SHARE_SAVE_KIT')): ADDTOANY_SHARE_SAVE_KIT(); endif;
endwhile;`

Also it's better to follow the best practices and make all the changes in child theme, not the one you bought. This little trick will save you a lot of time in the future.

Comment: also [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22900339/how-to-put-socail-share-button-in-wordpress-post-under-the-post-excerpt) leads to a similar question

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply I really appreciate it. Where about on the Valenti theme should I p;ace the above code ?

Comment: I have been trying to implement it for a long time but cant seem to see where I can place the code. Thanks so much for helping me :)

Comment: @MannyRibera when you use premium or contributed theme it is a good practice to make all your changes in child theme. Check [this post in codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) for more information on how to create your child theme. You need to create (or just copy from parent theme) file called archive.php or index.php I'm not that familiar with Valenti theme, but it should work with one of those files.

Comment: @MannyRibera I've updated the answer with your code from the question. Check this and share you results.

Comment: Hi I have edited the op above with the code in archive.php just need to know where to past it |:)

Comment: @MannyRibera you should also have a file called `cat-style-a.php` can you share it's code? the posts output should be declared there.

Comment: Here's where you should paste your code (inside the `article` tag):

`<div class="cb-meta">

    <h2 class="h4"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php echo cb_byline(); ?>
    <div class="cb-excerpt"><?php echo cb_clean_excerpt( 210, false ); ?></div>
    <!-- your social buttons code here -->

  </div>`